# Excel | Index Match with Advanced Conditional Formatting

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

Problem: Index match Name to source array S[2] with Names and Dates (target)into date column below. If the value in the Date column is less than the current date minus the adjacent Period values color red.

```
Name Period Date
A      X  
B.     Y
C.     Z

Period = {(X, Y, Z)}
X = 30
Y = 18
Z = 36
```

I used index match with Index = (Source S, Match(Name, S, 0), 2)

This did not work and I received an error.